# Deleted File, Available Space Did Not Return

Tags: linux, centos, filesystems

On CentOS linux, I just deleted a large log file over 3gb on XFS file system. After deleting the file, the available file space did not return to the drive seen via `df -h`. Is there anything I can do to find the missing free space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either reboot or terminate the process that has the file open. So long as the file is still in use, its space cannot be freed.